# Automatically processing the email received and sending the response

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server

The project that I am working on is required to monitor an email account for new messages. I am free to decide the formatting of these messages so that it will be easier to parse the information contained in them. (like [Request code: xxxxxxxxx])

Based on request codes, I need to send an email response to the original sender. I haven't done anything like that before. Please can you suggest any scheme/API/library/code snippet?

I am using:

- Microsoft exchange server (email will be received on an email account of this server)
- Visual Studio 2008 (C#)

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search gives this:

- [Send Mail with SMTP/Exchange in C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1870.htm)
- [Reading MS Exchange email](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.exchange.development/topic13020.aspx)
- [C# Exchange Mailbox Checker](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.exchange.development/topic33087.aspx)
- [Removing Incoming Email in Exchange](http://ezinearticles.com/?Removing-Incoming-Email-in-MS-Exchange,-C-Example&id=214)

You could also setup a POP3 gateway and use POP3 to collect the email if you are the total owner of the email/account

EDIT: I would also stay clear of any attachments and just put your information in the body if security is not an issue

Answer (score 0):

Email MimeTypes & Parsing is no fun, but if you have to try: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/

A MSMQ might be a better alternative.